# Wordpress category.php not working in /?cat

Tags: php, wordpress

After updating *(or maybe not)* but some time before, when I'm going to category list page  **mysite.com/?cat=10** I'm getting not **category.php** template - it opens **single.php** Why?

I was trying to make  **category-10.php** *(just for test)* but still coming to **single.php**.
Where I should look about my problem?
The problem was with my ajax plugin his code is :

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Ajax content loader
 * Description: Load content througt ajax.
 * Version: 0.1
 * 
 */

 /**
  * Initialization. Add our script if needed on this page.
  */
 function ajax_content_init() {
    global $wp_query;

    // Add code to index pages.
    if( !is_singular() ) {  
        // Queue JS
        wp_enqueue_script(
            'load-posts',
            plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/load-posts.js',
            array('jquery'),
            '1.0',
            true
        );

        $wp_query->is_single = true;
    }
 }
 add_action('template_redirect', 'ajax_content_init');

 ?>
```

Any ideas what is wrong here?
It is for mobile version, how to activate him only for mobile? not for desktop?

Comment: How did you know that it is displaying `single.php`, also try to disable all the plugins and check.

Comment: Code of category.php or single.php ? But if i use a blank page with footer and header funcs, it also doesnt show.

Comment: I was searching by html code, which i getting.

Comment: That same HTML could be in your index.php

Comment: You can see generated classes in `<body />` tag, it will tell which page template you're viewing. If you're not sure edit your question with the code.

Comment: @Jacob88 Please do edit codes in your question for better view.

Comment: Thanks Rahil, the problem was with my plugin.

Answer (score -1):

Download the [WordPress Debug Bar Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar/).  It will add a button to your wp-admin bar that says "Debug".  When pressed, this button will show you the debug panel.  Find the tab in this debug panel that says "WP Query", and it should show you query vars and the template file that are being used.

This should help you figure out what query vars are being registered, and which template file is really loaded.

Answer (score -1):

You should read wordpress codex for [template_redirect](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) before trying to experiment things.

> This action hook executes just before WordPress determines which
>   template page to load.

What are you actually trying is:

```
if( !is_singular() ) {
```

If page is not a singular, means is not a template `page.php` or `single.php` it should execute the code.

So when you were at `category.php` it executed the code and sets the global `$wp_query` layer objects property `single` to `true`. So whatever template you were viewing at that time it will set that page as `single`.

Hope it helps.